# Python Serial Communication Receiving COMMAND UNKNOWN

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

So I'm trying to control a Thermo Scientific temperature bath over serial (USB-A to USB-B) and when I send a command I get the response "F001" telling me that that command is known. The format is "command" "carriage return" and here is what I have:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-A800dars', 9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=5) #no timeout=0
print(ser.name)                         # check which port was really used

ser.write(b'RT\r')                      # read internal temp
# TODO probably not getting 100 bytes here, need to find what to expect and whether or not to do a timeout
serial_response = ser.read(100)         # read up to one hundred bytes or as much is in the buffer
print(serial_response)
```

I've tried adding a \n after the \r , I've tried multiple other commands, I've included a space between the RT and the \r and I've set the baud rate on the temperature bath to the same as I am sending over serial. I've also made sure I used the right drivers here from http://www.ftdichip.com/FTDrivers.htm.

Any thoughts? I'm using a Mac, sending over a USB-A to USB-B cable, and I only get the F001 response when the temperature bath is on and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as it turns out I was given the incorrect manual by the manufacturer. After finding the correct one and now knowing the correct commands to send over serial all the above code works just fine.